# Comparing two dictionaries and return ONLY if all keys, values match

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that I want to compare and only return them if ALL values match. One of the dictionaries is an `ordereddict` while the other is a regular `dict`. Since I am learning python I thought I would use the `csv` module instead of `pandas`. `dictReader` returned an `ordereddict`. It is guaranteed that, with the exception of "name", all keys are in both dictionaries.

```
# Desired Result
odict_items([('name', 'Alice'), ('math', '87'), ('english', '81'), ('history', '74')])
odict_items([('name', 'Bob'), ('math', '87'), ('english', '85'), ('history', '87')])
odict_items([('name', 'Charlie'), ('math', '83'), ('english', '79'), ('history', '90')])
odict_items([('name', 'Dalia'), ('math', '91'), ('english', '70'), ('history', '81')])

personDict = {('math': 87), ('english': 81), ('history': 74)}

# returns "Alice"
```

This is my code but it seems to be comparing each key, value pair individually. I tried playing around with sets and lists but I still don't get it.

```
for row in database:
    for key, value in row.items():
        if key in personDict and int(value) == personDict[key]:
            print(row["name"])
        else:
            print("No match")
```

It gives me something like so at least I know something is working?

```
# Output
Alice
Alice
Alice
Alice
Charlie
No match
No match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `==` operator to compare dictionaries, this should solve your problem

```py
import itertools

personDict = {'math': 87, 'english': 81, 'history': 74}
row = {'name': 'Dalia', 'math': 87, 'english': 81, 'history': 74}

if personDict == dict(itertools.islice(row.items(), 1, len(row))):
  print(row["name"])
else:
  print("No Match")
```